# How using ref into examples Swagger?

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

JSON spec:

```
"responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Успешный ответ сервиса",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/BaseResponse"
            },
            "examples": {
              "application/json": {
                "status": true,
                "response": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Product"
                },
                "errors": null
              }
            }
          }
}
```

Result:
[image]

But I need:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "response": {
      "ProductNumber": "number",
      "Barcode": "number",
      "Length": 12,
      "Width": 34,
      "Height": 423,
      "Volume": 1232
    }
  },
  "errors": null
}
```

How I can using $refs into example array for custom format response?
It's a typical case, but I cannot found documentation for it. Thank you for you feedback.

Comment: Same question but about OpenAPI 3.0: [Open API inherited example data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47639926/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline examples do not support `$ref` - the example must be a complete example:

```
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "Успешный ответ сервиса",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/BaseResponse"
          },
          "examples": {
            "application/json": {
              "status": true,
              "response": {
                "ProductNumber": "number",
                "Barcode": "number",
                "Length": 12,
                "Width": 34,
                "Height": 423,
                "Volume": 1232
              },
              "errors": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Instead of using `responses.<code>.examples`, you can specify the example values in your `BaseResponse` schema, and Swagger UI will use those instead.

For example, you can add a complete example to your `BaseResponse` schema:

```javascript
  "definitions": {
    "BaseResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        ...
      },
      "example": {    // <------ schema-level example
        "status": true,
        "response": {
          "ProductNumber": "number",
          "Barcode": "number",
          "Length": 12,
          "Width": 34,
          "Height": 423,
          "Volume": 1232
        },
        "errors": null
      }
    }
  }
```

or use property-level examples:

```javascript
  "definitions": {
    "BaseResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "example": true           // <------
        },
        "response": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Product"
        },
        "errors": {
          "example": null           // <------
        }
      }
    },
    "Product": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ProductNumber": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "number"       // <------
        },
        "Length": {
          "type": "integer",
          "example": 12             // <------
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

I'd like to note that `"errors": null` and `"example": null` are not actually valid in OpenAPI 2.0 (fka Swagger), because it does not support nullable types. Nullable types are [supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#null) in OpenAPI 3.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

I'v tried many solutions, the only one that seems to work is using 'examples' key and not 'example'.
then put a single example (you should name it) and put the $ref under it.

just like this:

```
"responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Успешный ответ сервиса",
            "schema": 
              "$ref": "#/definitions/BaseResponse"
            "examples":
              "example_name": # You can give as an example name any name you want
                $ref: "#/examples/200_res"

examples:
  200_res:
    description: example for 200_res
    value:
      {
        "status": true,
        "response": {
          "ProductNumber": "number",
          "Barcode": "number",
          "Length": 12,
          "Width": 34,
          "Height": 423,
          "Volume": 1232
        },
        "errors": null
      }
```

also notice you have problems with your `{ }` at the example you added